# Handling Nodata values in sklearn (working w pyimpute)

Tags: python, classification, rasterio, nodata, scikit-learn

I'm using sklearn for a classification project. Because I'm relatively new to doing geospatial tasks outside of a GUI, I'm using Matt Perry's [pyimpute](https://github.com/perrygeo/pyimpute/blob/master/src/pyimpute/_main.py) (link has all the code for that module) to handle the heavy lifting of moving geospatial data into and out of sklearn-readable structures. It's built on rasterio and geopandas.

My ROI has a lot of zones that are irrelevant to the classification I'm trying to perform and I would prefer to just leave them out. If I include them in the classification, it will spuriously inflate the global accuracy of my model. But none of the materials I've managed to find on the topic address setting nodata masks for machine learning.

Is there a (relatively) simple way to accomplish this?

(I haven't posted any of my own code because this is a pretty general question)

Comment: Which classification algorithm/s are you working with in `sklearn`?

Comment: I'm using RF classifier.